# Unclear Architecture of MNIST Neural Network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, object-detection, mnist

I am trying to reproduce a Neural Network trained to detect whether there is a 0-3 digit in an image with another confounding image. The paper I am following lists the corresponding architecture:

> A neural network with 28×56 input neurons and one output neuron is
> trained on this task. The input values are coded between −0.5 (black)
> and +1.5 (white). The neural network is composed of a first detection
> pooling layer with 400 detection neurons sum-pooled into 100 units
> (i.e. we sum-pool non-overlapping groups of 4 detection units). A
> second detection-pooling layer with 400 detection neurons is applied
> to the 100-dimensional output of the previous layer, and activities
> are sum-pooled onto a single unit representing the deep network
> output. Positive examples (0-3 digit in the image) are assigned target
> value 100 and negative examples are assigned target value 0. The
> neural network is trained to minimize the mean-square error between
> the target values and its output.

My main doubt is in this context what they mean by detection neurons, if they mean filters or a single standard ReLU neuron. Also, if the mean filters, how could they be applied in the second layer to a 100-dimensional output when they are designed to operate on 2x2 matrixes.

Reference:

> Montavon, G., Bach, S., Binder, A., Samek, W., & Müller, K. (2015).
> Explaining NonLinear Classification Decisions with Deep Taylor
> Decomposition. arXiv. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2016.11.008.

Specifically section 4.C

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I think you can strike all "detection" from the text. they use it like punctuation. it probably means "fully connected". same (striking) would probably work for "neuron(s)" too. "pooling" isn't FC but convolutional.

Comment: best contact the authors. they write "activities" instead of "activations". there appears to be a language barrier. they don't use established terms quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess at this is something like (code not tested - just rough PyTorch):

```py
from torch import nn

class Model(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Flatten(),  # Flatten row-wise into a 1D sequence
      nn.Linear(28 * 56, 400),  # Linear layer with 400 outputs.
      nn.AvgPool1D(4, 4),  # Sum pool to 100 outputs.
   )
   self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Linear(100, 400),  # Linear layer with 400 outputs.
      nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1D(1), # Sum pool to 1 output.
   )

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.layer2(self.layer1(x))
```

But overall I would agree with the commentor on your post that there are some issues with language here.